# How to get offset field or line number in tail plugin?

Tags: fluent-bit

I deployed a fluent-bit to ouput the pod's logs to elasticsearch, then displayed with kibana.
However, we have multiple logs at the same time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck0na.png)
The logs we searched from kibana may not be in the right order.
So, can we get the offset or line number?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: If you can augment your log(producer) to add those field then you can leverage 
[parsers](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/parsers) and/or filter[https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters] and specifically [lua] (https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/lua)